# How to create the best Drupal 7 structure as a site builder - via Entity type or Content type?

Tags: drupal, properties, drupal-7, entity

Just started using Drupal and tried to understand the core concepts. I have a developer background but I would like to use Drupal as a site builder and not digging into the code.

I'm trying to build a website which lists various vendors. One could be a Restaurant, another can be Photographer and other possible services (I have like 15 different ones). 
They all have some things in common like Title, a Location (used Taxonomy/Vocabulary for that), description, image gallery, address, website, office hours and so on.

But they also have some custom fields. Restaurants can have fields like Facility options:Parking, Smoking area, etc or Capacity; Photographers can have others.
So there are lots of fields which are common for each vendor and some are are unique per each vendor.

What's the best way to implement this kind of structure as a Site builder?
I tried using Entities via ECK (Entity Construction Kit) and defining Entity types (as Vendor) and Bundles (as specific Vendors) but then I'm really limited in defining the common fields on Entity type level since Properties does not seem to be flexible in this regard, meaning that I cannot define them as normal fields and can't associate to them various widgets but only as a text input. Not sure if this a limitation of ECK or of Drupal 7 itself?
On the other hand I see the option of creating normal Content types for each kind of vendor which seems like alot of repetitive work, not sure if this is the right way (that's my only option at the moment)?

Maybe I should start learning more of Drupal and do some coding to create specific entity types? - but this means being more than a site builder. Since it will be a big project will this save me of some trouble later on or you see that I can accomplish the task easily without this extra effort?
Also by coding I'm not sure if there are easy ways of defining fields/widgets for Entity type Properties.

I would later on want to use faceting as well for filtering which will be based both on the fields which are common and unique for each vendor type, not sure if this is an important factor when creating the structure.

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Have a read of these links, they all help to give an insite into this topic: 

[When is it appropriate to create an Entity versus just adding a new content type?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22586/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-an-entity-versus-just-adding-a-new-content-type)
[Custom Content Types VS Manually Created Tables](https://drupal.org/node/2086029)
[When to Use Content Types, Taxonomies, and Custom Entities in Drupal](http://www.4sitestudios.com/blog/sep-13-2013/when-use-content-types-taxonomies-and-custom-entities-drupal)

Comment: Or [When to use custom developed drupal entity types?](http://rapiddg.com/blog-post/when-use-custom-developed-drupal-entity-types)

Comment: Thanks Felix! While I've already read some of these, going again through all of the links made it more clear that in my case - where I don't really want to go into the code and pretty much all of the vendors need the node capabilities (content publishing, easily defining fields, using extra modules, etc) - it's better if I stick to using the Content types although ~70% of the fields will be the same between them.

Comment: Sounds like you've made the right choice then based on that. If I can get away with using a content type I will as is much more work once you start with custom entities...